# new instance / constructor of Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.DataCollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm

How to create a new instance of `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.DataCollection<T>` class? I've done it by following code, but it doesn't seem all right to me:

```csh
DataCollection<Entity> dc = (new EntityCollection()).Entities;
```

Comment: What error is throwing? Maybe remove the initial '(' to `DataCollection<Entity> dc = new EntityCollection()).Entities;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.DataCollection<T>` class does not have a public constructor, so you cannot use it the way you are showing.

As an alternative you can design a collection class of your own and implement the `ICollection<T>` interface or any other interface you need.